# Strong named assembly needed for COM interoperability?

Tags: c#, c++, com

I have several C# assembly libraries, which are not strongly named (signed). I would like to make a SxS COM-wrapper over those components using the tlbexp.exe to consume in native programs. Is it necessary to sign them or is there another way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have the C++ tag?  I don't see any reference to the C++ language in your post.  Also, assemblies and COM are not part of the C++ standard language.

Answer (score 2):

There are strong misconceptions in this question, it confuzzles the roles of two programmers.  You are the author of the library, somebody else uses your library and probably works for another company and has no idea who you are.  The client programmer.  You in turn have no idea how the client programmer uses your library, how many programs he wrote and what he does to deploy your library on his users' machines.  You run Tlbexp.exe only to help him write his code.

This is a recipe for trouble, like it is no matter what language or tooling you use when you create libraries.  That trouble starts when you make a change in the library and the client programmer has to rebuild and redeploy his programs that use your library.

There is extra trouble in a COM library because by default registration is machine-wide.  Which is pretty nice if the change you made is a bug-fix, all of the client programs that use your library automatically get the fix.  But it is not nice if the change is breaking and causes the old client program to fail.  The standard disaster is that the client programmer rebuilds *some* of this programs but forgets or ignores some old ones he no longer maintains.  The end-user is often the real victim, he's got a program that crashes but two programmers that don't think it is their problem to fix.

What is necessary is that programs that the client programmer does not update keep using the old version of your library so it is unaffected by the change.  In other words, there need to be multiple copies of your DLL on the users machine and a program automagically needs to pick the right one.

Thankfully that is easy to do for a [ComVisible] .NET assembly.  Either the client programmer, his user or an installer you provide for him can put the assembly in the GAC.  Which allows multiple copies of an assembly to exist side-by-side and the CLR can automatically find the correct one.  That has *two* requirements.  You need to bump the [AssemblyVersion] of your library, that's standard.  And the assembly needs to have a strong name so it can be put in the GAC.  That is trivial to do by you, using Project > Properties > Signing and ticking the "Sign the assembly" checkbox.  This has no security implications so the key doesn't matter and a password is entirely unnecessary.  It is *not* easy to do by the client programmer so this is something that you *must* do.  Always.

The client programmer also has the option to use isolated COM with a manifest (aka "regfree COM"), probably what you meant with "SxS COM-wrapper".  With the benefit that each program he writes has its own copy of the DLL, the way it works by default in .NET.  Bug-fixes need to be deployed manually but a change in your library can't break an unmaintained client program.  But this is entirely his choice, there is nothing that you can do to ensure that this is done.  You *must* assume that he doesn't use it, and he almost certainly won't at first, so you can't bypass the need to strong-name.

Answer (score 0):

When an assembly is strongly named, its types can only be used from other strongly named assemblies. Since your assemblies are not strongly named, there's no need to sign your COM wrapper.

Signing an assembly makes it possible to place it in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC). This has the benefit of keeping multiple versions side by side, without breaking existing clients.

The alternative is to use the Windows registry via [regasm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/regasm-exe-assembly-registration-tool)'s `/codebase` switch. Much in the same way as classic COM components are set up, this option registers your COM-visible assembly on a system wide basis.

Since you wish to deploy your COM wrapper via SxS / Registration-Free activation, thereby bypassing the registry and GAC altogether, there's really no need sign it.